# In ios how to add an observer to a method?

Tags: ios, addobserver

I'm using a plugin,there is a method "A" in the plugin's pluginClass.
if "A" is called ,I want to call "B" in myCalss.Such as:

```
-(void)A{
  [myClass B];
}
```

But I don't want to modify the code in pluginClass.
Is there any way to add an observer to a method or similar?
Thank u.

Comment: You could swizzle it, I suppose...

Comment: I phrase my answer as "only acceptable option" because swizzling is always ugly :D

Comment: Actually now I'm using swizzle,I'm trying to look for any other ways.Such as:```- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMethodSignature *sayHi = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(sayHi)];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:sayHi selector:@selector(sayHiRunning) name:@"" object:nil];
    [self sayHi];
}

-(void)sayHiRunning{
    NSLog(@"bbbbbb");
}

-(void)sayHi{
    NSLog(@"aaaaaaa");
}```But it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidBerry "swizzling is always ugly" But legal, and fundamental to how certain Foundation features work. Key-value observing uses swizzling - and observing is what the OP want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The only acceptable option I can think of is to subclass the class from the plugin, and then within your subclass over the target method and forward it:

```
@implementation MyPluginClass : PluginClass

-(void) A {
    [super A];
    [myClass B];
}

@end
```

Comment: But I must not call "A",and the plugin it works automatically itself.

Comment: My code is based on the plugin,other developers will use the plugin too,so I can't create a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Seems really easy solution. Make your own method C that contains A function and add method B in C. Instead of calling A, then you call C.

```
// BEFORE

[pluginClass A]; // a call to method A that u use originally.

// AFTER

[self C];

-(void)C {
  [pluginClass A];
  [myClass B];
}
```

Comment: Thank u,but I must not to call "A" myself, it will be called by plugin all the time.And I just want to listen it.